# Query has_one that is a subset of a has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have some polymorphic rules that I keep track of changes on, and I'd like to query the very last (current) rule. I understand that I can use a belongs_to to keep track of that, but I'd like to keep the has_one. Here is a bit of the module

```
has_many :rule_transitions, class_name: "#{name}AppliedRuleTransition", dependent: :destroy

has_one :current_rule_transition, -> { order created_at: :desc }, class_name: "#{name}AppliedRuleTransition", inverse_of: model_name.param_key.to_sym
has_one :current_rule, through: :current_rule_transition, source: :rule
```

I'd like to query `current_rule`, but `rule_transitions` is queried in its entirety.

My current attempt is with postgres' `FIRST_VALUE`

```
scope :rule, lambda { |q|
  joins(:current_rule)
  .select("#{model_name.plural}.*, rules.id = FIRST_VALUE(#{model_name.param_key}_applied_rule_transitions.rule_id) OVER(PARTITION BY #{model_name.param_key}_applied_rule_transitions.id ORDER BY #{model_name.param_key}_applied_rule_transitions.created_at DESC)")
  .where(rules: { slug: q })
}
```

I don't understand that function well enough, though, and this still doesn't give me what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go with `belongs_to` instead and put a foreign key on the table. It will let you properly eager load the association to avoid n+1 issues - especially  the common case where you want a list of records and the latest associated item without loading the entire association.

It will also perform far better than the alternatives.

```
belongs_to :current_rule_transition, class_name: "#{name}AppliedRuleTransition"
has_many :rule_transitions, 
  class_name: "#{name}AppliedRuleTransition", 
  dependent: :destroy,
  after_add: ->(model, transition) { model.update(current_rule_transition: transition) }
```

No need to make things harder on yourself.

Comment: I had the same issue on a application with a huge amount of rows in the associated table and tried all kinds of novel solutions like lateral joins and struggled a bunch with getting rails to include/eager load the association to avoid n+1 queries and the fact that the query itself was really slow. Not worth the amount of effort wasted.

Comment: TIL about association callbacks!! I was avoiding this because I didn't want to risk things getting out of sync. Good call!